# Store header key and value using HttpResponseMessage, GetAsynch

Tags: c#, cookies, header, httpresponsemessage, getasync

I have the following code and I want to store all keys and values of the header (i.e. cookie, session id, etc) in KeyValuepair type of an object. How can I accomplish that?

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://google.com").Result;
        HttpHeaders headers = response.Headers;
```

I need those values because afterwards I will use the same cookies and sessionid to post to the website.

Comment: So I can just use it as it is, in my postrequest? if so, thank you for your input. :)

Comment: How can I get a specific value from the content of the get request response?

Comment: Not the header a specific value of lets say a form

Comment: Thank you, But I have already fixed this issue.